# Maintain Tab index after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Order page with 4 textboxes that are inside an ajax updatepanel. All the 4 have TextChanged events. None of the controls in this page have TabIndex property set. When I enter text in textbox1 & press the tab key, it causes postback, but the next focus is not on textbox2 as I want. The focus is on the page instead. Similarly with all the textboxes.

This Order page uses a master page.

Master page:

```
<form id = "form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1 " runat="server" />
```

Order page:

```
<asp:content id ="bodycontent" contentplaceholderID="maincontent" runat="server">
// 4 text boxes

</asp:content>
```

I cannot add another form or scriptmanager tag in the order page as it errors out saying there can be only instance of them.

So ,there is no FormOrder or ScriptManagerOrder in the Order page's code behind, but I would like to do something of the foll. way.
How can I do this.

```
protected void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //someFunction();
TextBox tb = (TextBox)FormOrder.FindControl("textbox2");
ScriptManagerOrder.SetFocus(tb);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //someFunction();
   TextBox tb = (TextBox)FormOrder.FindControl("textbox2");
   tb.focus();
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use another form and script manager in the order page as they already are in the master. The C# code in question was a method I would like to use

Comment: Ok try to refer below link
http://couldbedone.blogspot.in/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html

Comment: @Ruby It will work for you, no need to add another script manager on the page.

Comment: @nrsharma.. Thank you very much . it worked. All I had to do was put all the page content inside a div. <div id="FormOrder" runat="server>

Answer (score 0):

Add following script in js file called i.e focus.js:

```
var lastFocusedControlId = "";

function focusHandler(e) {
    document.activeElement = e.originalTarget;
}

function appInit() {
    if (typeof(window.addEventListener) !== "undefined") {
        window.addEventListener("focus", focusHandler, true);
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoadingHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);
}

function pageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {
    lastFocusedControlId = typeof(document.activeElement) === "undefined" 
        ? "" : document.activeElement.id;
}

function focusControl(targetControl) {
    if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
        var focusTarget = targetControl;
        if (focusTarget && (typeof(focusTarget.contentEditable) !== "undefined")) {
            oldContentEditableSetting = focusTarget.contentEditable;
            focusTarget.contentEditable = false;
        }
        else {
            focusTarget = null;
        }
        targetControl.focus();
        if (focusTarget) {
            focusTarget.contentEditable = oldContentEditableSetting;
        }
    }
    else {
        targetControl.focus();
    }
}

function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
    if (typeof(lastFocusedControlId) !== "undefined" && lastFocusedControlId != "") {
        var newFocused = $get(lastFocusedControlId);
        if (newFocused) {
            focusControl(newFocused);
        }
    }
}

Sys.Application.add_init(appInit);
```

Reference it using Scriptmanager like below:

```
<ajax:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <ajax:ScriptReference Path="~/Js/FixFocus.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </ajax:ScriptManager>
```

For more information check out below link:

http://couldbedone.blogspot.in/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for something from C# and simpler as I do not know JS.

Comment: No problem just use this script, name it focus.js and reference it as shown in ScriptManager. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to use server-side controls for a Tab. Why don't you use some jQuery/Bootstrap? 
With your current approach you use to many useless Posts/Postbacks overloading your server with a useless work.